# How to create a range of CGPoints (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, range, cgpoint

I have a line in my view(as UIImage). I want something to happen when an area is touched. How to create a range of CGPoints like with Integers?

I want to do something like this:

```
var range = CGPoint(x:155.0...160.0,y: 132.0...136.0)
```

And then check whether the touched point is in that range.

Comment: This question is very vague: What is a "range of points"? A rectangular area? A line? How does it map to an area? Why integers? What does this have to to with `UIImage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what your really need is a [GCRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGRect).

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 155, y: 132, width: 5, height: 4)
```

Then, to know if your touched point is inside this rect, just do:

```
rect.contains(touchedPoint)
```